# Rails 5 - what is a 'job' and why did they name it such

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, jobs

Upgrading to Rails 5, there are 'jobs' and an `app/jobs` directory. Googling for information related to "Rails jobs" spews forth pages of advertisements for employment using Rails...

So, what is a 'job' in Rails context; and why oh why did the Rails team have to use this name?

(We have an app/workers folder for dealing with async tasks, is it just new nomenclature for 'worker's or does a worker have many jobs?)

Comment: Apologies for the noob question - but I did not want to make assumptions, no matter how obvious the answer may seem

Comment: in your case, `jobs` and `workers` are the same.But in rails community it is like a rule to call them `job` and add to class name `Job`to the end. Like `SendEmailJob`.